how can I resolve this issue in android studio
I changed target SDK to 33 and it didn't work. Getting this error.
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
      > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)


Please make an effort to format your post for legibility.

Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Kindly provide your buildToolsVersion from build.gradle(Module: Android).

You're not telling us what exactly it is you're trying to do, what the environment is, or what commands you have given to get this output. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

It may cause after updating the com.android.tools.build:gradle version. So you also have to update the Google services.
